# Cloud service to send monthly email IoT sensor data

Tags: database, cloud-service, cloud, iot

I am trying to develop a smart energy meter project in his the energy consumption and bill amount are calculated by Node mcu and sends data to cloud ,the cloud database should send this data to customers via email  (monthly once) ,which platform should I use.